# Jenkins slack plugin slackUserIdsFromCommitters returning empty list

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-slack-plugins

I'm trying to send slack direct messages to committers from a jenkins pipeline, using the jenkins slack plugin.

Sending to a channel works, as does sending a direct message after using `slackUserIdFromEmail` to get an id from a hardcoded email address.

But `slackUserIdsFromCommitters` returns an empty list. And similarly setting `notifyCommitters` to true on sending to a channel doesn't send to anyone.

I've not seen any useful debugging information.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, just discovered yesterday when attempting to use `slackUserIdsFromCommitters()` for the first time. I have a custom Jenkins Slack app, with all the necessary scopes (including `users:read` and `users:read.email`).